# Android: Public Key initialization

Tags: android, public-key-encryption, x509, encryption

I want to initialize a PublicKey with a String such as `23441AB…2583DA==`

```
PublicKey publicKey=null;
Cipher publicKeyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
publicKeyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

When I pass an empty key I get the following exception:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA

Even if I pass a Key publicKey, says that the key type is unknown.

I have seen that the proper way to initialize a PublicKey is:

```
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
publicKey = kp.getPublic();
```

But I don't want a random key, I want the key from a specific String.

**EDIT**: I have found the way to convert an array of bytes to a PublicKey, but I am still getting an exception.

I want to initialize a PublicKey with a publicKey String that stores its encoded format: `[B@41588dd0`. It is already decoded from Base64. The PublicKey was created with RSA and initialized with 128 bits.

```
byte [] pkArray=publicKey.getBytes();
X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pkArray);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pKey =keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec); //get the exception here
Cipher publicKeyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
publicKeyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

When I pass the EncodedKeySpec I get the following exception:

> java.security.InvalidKeySpecException: java.io.EOFException: DEF length 66 object truncated by 57

Comment: Can you post your public key? We can help determine the format and advise on how to import.

Comment: Hi @DuncanJones, please have a look at my EDIT section.